# Check Each Value In Range On Last Row [VBA]

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a sheet set up to get the contents of the last row. I want to check the values on that last row from J to W. I want to check if all the values are "YES" and if so return an OK into a variable. Here is what I have so far, it should be clear from the below what I am trying to do:

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sName = ActiveSheet.Name

For Each c In Worksheets(sName).Range(Cells(J, lastRow), Cells(W, lastRow))
    If c.Value = "YES" Then
       vData = "OK"
    Else
        vData = "Error."
    End If
Next c
```

Thanks.

Comment: One thing to note, I believe lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row will give you the last row that has something in column A.

Comment: I agree with MatthewD - in your situation it may be better to use .UsedRange, which gives the full area of a sheet to the rightmost and bottommost alignment where a cell is 'used'. Note that this includes formatting changes, which may not be what you want (ie: if your last value is in D10 but you have formatting in C11, it will give you D11).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cells(x,y)` takes two **integers** as arguments, and it's **row, column** not column, row!

Try

```
For Each c In Sheets(sName).Range(Cells(lastRow, 10), Cells(lastRow, 23))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. All worked, but for some reason didn't with Worksheets(sName) so I removed and it worked fine anyway as I was using the macro within the worksheet I wanted.

Comment: Sorry ... Have updated my answer ... it should be `Sheets(sName)`. If you don't have the `Sheets()` bit then the macro will run on the `ActiveSheet` which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
lRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

lCol = 10
Do While lCol <= 21
    If ws.Cells(lRow, lCol).Value <> "YES" Then
        vData = "Error."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    lCol = lCol + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Public Sub checking()

    Dim lastRow As Long

    'Here, I take row count by using column "J"
    'You can modify it if you need
    lastRow = Sheets("sheetname").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For Each cell In Sheets("sheetname").Range("J" & lastRow & ":W" & lastRow)

        If cell.Value = "YES" Then

            vData = "OK"

        Else

            vData = "Error."

            Exit For

        End If

    Next cell

    'Show result
    MsgBox vData

End Sub
```